# Round up numbers with residue

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

This code rounds up only the subvalues bigger or equal to 5:

```
Math.round(2.5) = 3
Math.round(2.4) = 2
```

I would like to get the following:

```
Math.round(2.0000000001) = 3
Math.round(2.0) = 2
```

How do I round up any integer with non-zero residue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil):

```
Math.ceil(2.0000000001) = 3
```

Comment: what about a bitwise operator?

Comment: Perhaps he meant `| 0` one. But this op will just truncate the decimal part of the number literal.

Answer (score 2):

With [**Math.ceil**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil):

```
Math.ceil(2.0000000001) === 3; // true
```

Note, though, that some numbers won't be represented internally as ones greater than 2, even though they look like it:

```
Math.ceil(2.000000000000001) === 3;  // true
Math.ceil(2.0000000000000001) === 3; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [**Math.ceil**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp) - `Math.ceil(2.0000000001)`

> The ceil() method rounds a number UPWARDS to the nearest integer

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/x7adn/)